# What are the configuration required for server and client side configurations on a MEAN Stack applications?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

What configurations are needed to be done while kick-starting a mid-level enterprise application for MEAN Stack. How should the configurations be done with Angular 2/4/5 and NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

The nodejs part is frontend framework agnostic so it can be accessed using any front end framework via api's. eg: Angular, React, Ember

For your node setup you would probably want to use express along with a few middlewares and manage your db operations.
You can use an express generator to build the initial folder structure.

I recommend using the following packages with your node app -

- helmet(middleware for security)
- morgan(middleware for logging)
- mongoose(to connect to mongodb)
- dotenv(for config files)
- got(light and quick library for requests)
- lodash(utility library)
- nodemon(for automatic server restart on file changes)